# Use Sparklyr to join tables from 2 different databases

Tags: r, sparklyr

This is my current way after I invoke a Sparklyr session:

```
dbGetQuery(sparkContext, "USE DB_1")

df_1 <- tbl(sparkContext, "table_1")

dbGetQuery(sparkContext, "USE DB_2")

df_2 <- tbl(sparkContext, "table_2")

df <- df_1 %>% inner_join(df_2, by = c("col_1" = "col_2"))

nrow(df))
```

Errors that are I met with:

```
"Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: table_1"
```

My take is Sparklyr does not (directly) support joining tables from 2 databases. I am wondering if anyone has an elegant solution to this problem

Comment: Have you tried tbl_cache(sc, name, force = TRUE)? Such as with: my_var <- tbl_cache(sc,name= "hive_iris") to load the tables before switching schemas?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the database in the Spark SQL syntax passed to the dbGetQuery function, e.g.:

```
df_1 <- dbGetQuery(sc, "select * from db_1.table_1")
```

However, note that dbGetQuery collects the data to the driver as an R dataframe, so you may want to do the join *within* dbGetQuery, e.g.:

```
df <- dbGetQuery(sc,"select * from db_1.table_1 A inner join db_2.table_2 B where A.col_1 = B.col_2)
```

(Or, if your datasets are really large but you want to aggregate via a more R-friendly API instead of Spark SQL, you can use SparkR.)

Answer (score 0):

From [the sparklyr book](https://therinspark.com/data.html#data-storage-systems), you can use the *dbplyr* package to create references to each table:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
library(sparklyr)
table_1 <- tbl(sc, dbplyr::in_schema("db_1", "table_1"))
table_2 <- tbl(sc, dbplyr::in_schema("db_2", "table_2"))
```

Then you can do a standard R merge:

```
df <- merge(table_1, table2, by.x = "col_1", by.x = "col_2")
```

(I'm doing this right now, but it's taking forever.)

Answer (score 0):

One more approach could be to create two separate Sparklyr dataframes, (one from each database respectively), and then do whatever you want. You may join them as Sparklyr dataframe, or convert back to R dataframe to join, whichever is appropriate as per the size of the data.

```
sdf_1 <- sparklyr::spark_read_table(sc, "first_table_name",
 options=list(dbtable="first_database_name.first_table_name"))

sdf_2 <- sparklyr::spark_read_table(sc, "second_table_name",
 options=list(dbtable="second_database_name.second_table_name"))

inner_join(sdf_1, sdf_2, by = c("col_1" = "col_2"))
```